# Python: Taking user input, converting to ASCII, but inserting NULL between each character

Tags: python, null, binary, ascii, converters

I'm trying to find a way of converting user input to ASCII, but with NULL inserted between each character.

```
user_input = input("Enter number: ")
ascii_input = user_input.encode('ascii')
ascii_input_with_null = "NULL".join(ascii_input)
```

This doesn't work, but I'm hoping it makes it quite clear what I'm trying to achieve...

Example:

User enters: "111"

Output is: b'049(value for NULL)049(value for NULL)049'

Bigger picture, I want the user to enter two numbers. One is to be searched for within a file, the other is to be the replacement. So I need to convert both of these numbers to ASCII, insert the NULL separators, then have them formatted in a way that I can use to do this find and replace... Not sure if it's possible (as my googling doesn't seem to return anything useful) to write "NULL" in some way as text that could then be converted with .encode('ascii')?

Thanks

Comment: your mean is ord("1") ?

Answer (score 0):

```
rl = [str(ord(i)) for i in user_input]

"NULL".join(rl)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't quite what I mean. If user input was "111", I wouldn't want the output to be: 49NULL49NULL49NULL, I'd want it to be: b'49(actual value for NULL, not as text)49(actual value for NULL, not as text)49(actual value for NULL, not as text)